# Find $h(x)$ and $k(x)$ in $F[x]$ that : $f(x)h(x) + g(x)k(x) = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $F$ is a field. If $g(x),f(x) ∈ F[x]$, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are irreducible , and there is no polynomial of degree over $0$ in $F[x]$ that divide $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ prove that there are $h(x)$ and $k(x)$ in $F[x]$ that :

$f(x)h(x) + g(x)k(x) = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be set of all combinations $fh+gk$. Among all non zero elements of $I$ choose one of minimal degree, say $p$. By considering Euclidian division of $f$ and $g$ by $p$, we see that $p$ divide both $f$ and $g$. So it must be constant, there exist $h,kl$ so that $c=fh+gk$, $1=f. (h/c)+g.( k/c)$.

Comment: Thanks but why p divide f and g???

Comment: $f=p.b+r$ with $r=0$ or $deg r < deg p$. But $r=f-pb$ is alos in $I$, and as $deg r < deg p$ it must be $0$.

Comment: thanks it was so simple and i think in hard ways :)